# objective-c why the same property but the different attribute

Tags: objective-c, properties, readonly

in a class,there is a situation:

```
@interface classA: NSObject
@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) NSString *testString;
@end

@interface classA()
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSString *testString;
@end
@implementation classA
@end
```

what's the advantage? Why this?

Answer (score 2):

That's a very common pattern.

Anyone including the header file for your class sees "readonly". Which means they can read to the property, but they cannot write to it. That's what you want for any property that you don't want any random bit of code to change.

In your implementation, you see "readwrite". So in your implementation of your class, you can write to it. However, only *you* can write to the property, nobody in another class can.

Answer (score 0):

It is so, because a programmer don't want users of this class to modify property `testString`, and at the same time do want to modify it by himself.

For example, property `description` of `NSObject` is readonly as well.

You can use this pattern, if you don't want to override getter, and instead to assign new value to your property when state of your instance changes.

Comment: Actually, description is not an instance method of NSObject. It is part of the NSObject protocol. And it isn't defined as a readwrite property anywhere.

Comment: You are right, I just give this as an example of why zhangsanfeng could use readonly property.